# Defining default value for new attributes in xml

Tags: android

I have defined a small attribute and style as following:

```
    <declare-styleable name="MyStyleable">
        <attr name="extraColor" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <style name="SpecialStyle">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/extraColor</item>
    </style>
```

and in the code I use `applyStyle()` to apply my style to the theme:

```
context.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.SpecialStyle, true);
```

Since I have used `?attr/extraColor` in my style, if someone defines `extraColor` in the base theme, that value automatically will be used in applying `SpecialStyle` and when no one defines `extraColor`, `null` will be used as value for applying `SpecialStyle`. I wonder if there is a way to define a default value for `extraColor` to use when it is not defined, rather than using `null`.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not always make it defined in the base theme? Why leave it undefined? If you dont mind.

Comment: @PrinceAli Because this code is inside a library. I don't have access to library user's theme. I like to use a non-null default value in case that library user forgets to add this value inside their theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered my question, I thought it is better to share the idea that I found. It appears that this method works.

First we define a style with default values:

```
    <style name="SpecialStyleDefault">
        <item name="extraColor">@color/mycolor</item>
    </style>
```

then we use a code like this:

```
context.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.SpecialStyleDefault, false);
context.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.SpecialStyle, true);
```

In this way, if `extraColor` is **not** defined, it will be applied first. Then we force our special style which now will use default style if not defined, or user defined `extraColor` if it is already available in style.